# jsoup parsing string value in android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am learning jsoup. I want to  parse the  below script :

```
<script>
_cUq="1lj9lodlnq";
</script>
```

After parsing `output :  1lj9lodlnq`
Here is what I am trying:

```
String  str  = element.ownText().toString();
str = str.replace("\r","");
str = str.replace("\n","");
str = str.replace("<script>","");
str = str.replace("</script>","");

System.out.println(str);
if(str.contains("="))
    split = str.split("=");
```

On debugging I can see the script is stored in the element tag but on assigning to str I get "". Correct me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the inner Javascript with Jsoup. This has the plus that your code is much easier to maintain. Also, you can use regular expressions to rule out the whitespaces instead of String.replace() them one by one.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class JSoupSO {

    @Test
    public void script() {
        String s = "<script>\n" +
                "_cUq=\"1lj9lodlnq\";\n" +
                "</script>";

        // let Jsoup parse the HTML
        String innerJavascript = Jsoup.parse(s).data();

        // remove all whitespaces
        innerJavascript = innerJavascript.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        assertThat(innerJavascript, is("_cUq=\"1lj9lodlnq\";"));
    }

}
```